# ffmpeg generates file with only audio from ts

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to get some parts of a ts video and then merge them into a new video. The problem is that when doing the split, the video is lost. The splits only contains audio. Here is the video source information:

ffmpeg -i source_file.ts

```
ffmpeg version 3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '97274181.ts':
Duration: 00:02:30.70, start: 60.000000, bitrate: 3582 kb/s
Program 1 
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 139 kb/s
Stream #0:1[0x101]: Video: h264 (Main) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, unknown/bt709/unknown), 1920x1080, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 90k tbn, 2k tbc
Stream #0:2[0x102]: Data: timed_id3 (ID3  / 0x20334449)
At least one output file must be specified
```

This is the command used for doing the split:

```
ffmpeg -ss 10 -i source_file.ts -t 5 -c copy cut1.ts
```

And this is the video information after the cut:

```
ffmpeg version 3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[NULL @ 0x7fc9ba008000] start time for stream 0 is not set in estimate_timings_from_pts
[mpegts @ 0x7fc9b9800000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'siri1.ts':
Duration: 00:00:05.08, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 148 kb/s
Program 1 
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service01
  service_provider: FFmpeg
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Stream #0:1[0x101]: Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 120 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

If I reproduce cut1.ts I can only hear the audio. Video is gone.

Comment: You should show the console output from the command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard which command? The output I've put here is from the output of the commands.

Comment: BTW Thanks to the answers of mulvya and VC.one I've tried the same conversions but changing the -t from 5 to something else like 9 and then it worked. I guess the problem is the frame rate of the ts

Answer (score 2):

Try these three ways, in that order

## 1

```
ffmpeg -i source_file.ts -ss 10 -t 5 -c copy cut1.ts
```

## 2

```
ffmpeg -analyzeduration 20M -probesize 20M -ss 10 -i source_file.ts -t 5 -c copy cut1.ts
```

## 3

```
ffmpeg -i source_file.ts -c copy -dn source.mp4
```

& then

```
ffmpeg -ss 10 -i source.mp4 -t 5 -c copy cut1.ts
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1) Uses slow seek and the result is the same than the command I put as an example. 2) Also have the same effect than 1) or my example. 3) Generates a video that opens but ends really fast.

Comment: `-analyzeduration 200M -probesize 200M` helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect seeking 10 seconds into the video is not hitting a video **keyframe**, so best to just re-encode rather than try to copy a non-keyframe onwards. Audio can be copied since all audio frames are classed as keyframes.

Try:

```
ffmpeg -ss 10 -i source_file.ts -t 5 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 cut1.ts
```

Comment: This is not the issue. See this error message from the console : `[mpegts @ 0x7fc9b9800000] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none): unspecified size`. And in the console from the output, the video is present but attributes are missing.

Comment: Do you mean the SPS and PPS of h264 codec? But doesn't using `codec copy` force FFmpeg to direct copy from timestamp of 10 secs. A direct copy might make the first frame of output hold some non-keyframe bytes (hence no SPS or PPS) and therefore leads to error `Could not find codec parameters for stream`...

Comment: FFmpeg always splits at GOP boundaries in copy mode. Depending on container, it either shifts output timestamps or assigns negative TS to frames not meant to be presented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This command has the same result than the one I was using: a video that only contains audio.